# python pandas double aggregation function with nth(0)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

The following pandas aggregation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a' : [1,1,1,1],
    'b' : [1,2,3,4],
    'c' : [np.nan,6,7,8],
    })

r = df.groupby('a').agg({
    'b' : 'mean',
    'c' : 'nth(0)',
    })
```

obviously gives:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nth(0)'
```

(I would use `'first'` for this, but it gives the first non null value and I want to include them).

So, how to use the `nth` aggregation function on `c` toghether with `mean` on `b`?

I know that this works but it's not so nice:

```
df.groupby('a').agg({
    'b' : 'mean',
    'c' : lambda s:s.iloc[0],
    })
```

Comment: do you mean `'first'`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom function:

```
r = df.groupby('a').agg({
    'b' : 'mean',
    'c' : lambda x: x.iloc[0],
    })
```

If needed, use a named function, which makes it nicer:

```
def nth(x, i=0):
    return x.iloc[i]

r = df.groupby('a').agg({
    'b' : 'mean',
    'c' : nth,
    })
```

Or, maybe even nicer, with a function factory:

```
def nth(i):
    def nth_(x):
        return x.iloc[i]
    return nth_

r = df.groupby('a').agg({
    'b' : 'mean',
    'c' : nth(0),
    })
```

Output:

```
     b    c
a          
1  2.5  nan
```

Comment: A pipe function that creates a dataframe with nth also works and should be efficient, albeit not beautiful to the eyes